# How to convert array of working hours into 24 hour format?

Tags: php, arrays, format, hour

I have a set of arrays like this in PHP.

```
  ["Monday"]=> string(7) "8AM-4PM" 
  ["Tuesday"]=> string(7) "8AM-4PM" 
  ["Wednesday"]=> string(7) "8AM-4PM" 
  ["Thursday"]=> string(7) "8AM-4PM" 
  ["Friday"]=> string(6) "Closed" 
  ["Saturday"]=> string(7) "8AM-4PM" 
  ["Sunday"]=> string(7) "8AM-4PM" }
```

How to I convert the hours into 24 hour format?

Comment: do you hard code this array or do you get it from a function or API response?

Comment: @VijayHardaha it's from an API response

Comment: @AndraYogi Always share a var_export() of your input array instead of var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll have to loop through your array, then you'll have to check if the value has AM or PM because we don't want to transform **Closed** then you'll have to split the value by **"-"** then get an array of times and loop through it and then `date` and `strtotime` function you'll convert it to 24 hour time then you'll join the array with **"-"** again.

Here is the working code:

```php
// Define data.
$data = array(
    'Monday'    => '8AM-4PM',
    'Tuesday'   => '8AM-4PM',
    'Wednesday' => '8AM-4PM',
    'Thursday'  => '8AM-4PM',
    'Friday'    => 'Closed',
    'Saturday'  => '8AM-4PM',
    'Sunday'    => '8AM-4PM',
);

// Creaye empty array to store transformed data.
$new_data = array();

// Loop through data.
foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
    // Check if the value has am or pm
    if ( strpos( strtolower( $value ), 'am' ) !== false || strpos( strtolower( $value ), 'pm' ) !== false ) {
        // split time from "-"
        $times = explode( '-', $value );
        // create an empty array to store transformed time.
        $new_times = array();
        // loop through times array.
        foreach ( $times as $time ) {
            // convert to 24 format.
            $new_times[] = date( 'HA', strtotime( $time ) );
        }
        // join the transformed times array with "-"
        // and store in new data.
        $new_data[ $key ] = join( '-', $new_times );
    } else {
        // if the value has no am or pm, just store it.
        $new_data[ $key ] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump( $new_data );
```

**Here is the shorter version for the same thing, but it might be difficult for you to understand**

```php
// Define data.
$data = array(
    'Monday'    => '8AM-4PM',
    'Tuesday'   => '8AM-4PM',
    'Wednesday' => '8AM-4PM',
    'Thursday'  => '8AM-4PM',
    'Friday'    => 'Closed',
    'Saturday'  => '8AM-4PM',
    'Sunday'    => '8AM-4PM',
);

$data = array_map(
    function( $value ) {
        return strpos( strtolower( $value ), 'am' ) !== false || strpos( strtolower( $value ), 'pm' ) !== false ? join(
            '-',
            array_map(
                function( $time ) {
                    return date( 'HA', strtotime( $time ) );
                },
                explode( '-', $value )
            )
        ) : $value;
    },
    $data
);

var_dump( $data );
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has easy to use date and string format functions.

This loops over the array, and splits the time and reformats it.

```
$times = [
    'Monday'    => '8AM-4PM',
    'Tuesday'   => '8AM-4PM',
    'Wednesday' => '8AM-4PM',
    'Thursday'  => '8AM-4PM',
    'Friday'    => 'Closed',
    'Saturday'  => '8AM-4PM',
    'Sunday'    => '8AM-4PM',
];

$time24 = [];
foreach ($times as $day => $time) {
    [$from, $to] = explode('-', $time);
    $time24[$day] = null === $to
        ? $from
        : sprintf('%02d:00-%02d:00', date('H', strtotime($from)), date('H', strtotime($to)));
}

print_r($time24);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [Monday]    => 08:00-16:00
    [Tuesday]   => 08:00-16:00
    [Wednesday] => 08:00-16:00
    [Thursday]  => 08:00-16:00
    [Friday]    => Closed
    [Saturday]  => 08:00-16:00
    [Sunday]    => 08:00-16:00
)
```